# При одиночной вставке в таблицу ошибка: ORA-00934: групповая функция здесь не разрешена

Tags: sql, oracle

Пытаюсь заполнить таблицу значениями:

```
create table cities(name varchar2(100));
insert into cities(name) values('Москва ');
insert into cities(name) values('Москва');
insert into cities(name) values('Москва ');
insert into cities(name) values('Тверь ');
insert into cities(name) values('Тверь ');
insert into cities(name) values('Севастополь ');

select length(name)-length(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(name,'а',''),'е',''),'ё',''),'и',''),'о' ,''), 'у',''),'ы',''), 'э', ''),'ю', ''), 'я', '')) from cities where replace(name, ' ', '')='Москва'
drop table answ;
create table answ(name varchar(100), num1 int, num2 int, num3 int)
insert into answ(name) values('Москва');
insert into answ(num2) values(min(length(name)-length(REPLACE(name, ' ', ''))) from cities where replace(name, ' ', '')='Москва') where name='Москва';
insert into answ(name) values('Тверь');
insert into answ(name) values('Севастополь');
select * from answ
```

Но выводитсят ошибка следующего характера:

```
Error starting at line : 12 in command -
insert into answ(num2) values(min(length(name)-length(REPLACE(name, ' ', ''))) from cities where replace(name, ' ', '')='Москва') where name='Москва'
Error at Command Line : 12 Column : 31
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00934: групповая функция здесь не разрешена
00934. 00000 -  "group function is not allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Какой нафиг VALUES? читайте про INSERT .. SELECT.

Comment: нет, друг, я не оправдываюсь. обидно, но справедливо.

Comment: Это - шоры. Как приучились с самого начала, что раз INSERT, то непременно VALUES - так всё, иные варианты забыты. Экономия мышления... жаль, но надо бы обучать сперва именно универсальному INSERT..SELECT, и только потом рассказывать про INSERT..VALUES (который может всегда быть преобразован в INSERT..SELECT - но не всегда наоборот) - ох, сколько бы вопросов вообще не было задано...

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-00926: отсутствует ключевое слово VALUES

Comment: Как тогда добавить несколько вычисляемых из другой таблицы значений?

Comment: Получить их в SELECT - можешь? если да - формируешь выходной набор (поля, выражения, литералы), который соответствует структуре пополняемой таблицы, и добавляешь впереди INSERT INTO.

Comment: Я в написанном коде ни хрена не понял - ни логику запроса, ни логику заполнения второй таблицы... но посмотри вот это: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c9afc2f4b73ad26b37d68ba89f3f5af0

Comment: При добавлении этого length(name)-length(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(name,'а',''),'е',''),'ё',''),'и',''),'о' ,''), 'у',''),'ы',''), 'э', ''),'ю', ''), 'я', '')) в запрос на добавление я получаю ошибку

Comment: вся проблема заключается именно в том. что "групповая функция не является одногруппной"

Comment: вообще ВСЯ проблема заключается в том, что я не понимаю, как добавить именно такое вычисленное значение

Comment: Типичная XY. Давайте так. Вместо своих попыток решить публикуете саму задачу. Ну или попытки решить  оставьте - но как дополнение к задаче.

Comment: проблема решена, для корректной работы необходимо было в каждом заполненном поле использовать функции по типу min max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если надо получить значение для одиночной вставки запросом, то сделайте, как в следующем воспроизводимом примере:

```
create table t (nam varchar2 (8), num int)
/
insert into t values ('objmaxid', (select max (object_id) from user_objects))
/
select * from t;

NAM             NUM
-------- ----------
objmaxid     103491
```

Comment: извините, что закрыл так поздно